# Got wrong data while split file into arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, split

I have file contains two lines and each line contains 200 fields and I would like to split it into arrays

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(pathSensorsCalc))
{
     string s = String.Empty;
     while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) == null) { };
     String line1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
     String line2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
     CalcValue[0] = new String[200];
     CalcValue[1] = new String[200];
     CalcValue[0] = line1.Split(' ');
     CalcValue[1] = line2.Split(' ');
}
```

After the code above, `CalcValue[1]` is empty and `CalcValue[0]` contains data of the second line (instad of the first one). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When using

```
sr.ReadToEnd()
```

, you are reading to the end of your input stream. That means, after the first call of

```
String line1 = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

your stream is already at the last position. Replace your `ReadToEnd()` call with `ReadLine()` calls. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows OS, a new line is represented by `\r\n`. So you should not split the lines by spaces (`" "`).

Which means you should use another overload of the `Split` method - `Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)`. The first argument is the characters you want to split by and the second is the options. Why do you need the options? Because if you split by 2 continuous characters you get an empty element.

So now it is easy to understand what this code does and why:

```
line1.Split (new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: You could also use the constant Environment.NewLine instead of directly creating an char array, if I am not wrong.

Comment: @ThomasSymalla Yes you are right. But I just want the OP to know more about the Windows OS instead of just not knowing what the value of `Environment.NewLine` is.

Comment: @Sweeper 
I did as you suggested and I have problem now with CalcValue[1][199] that contains this value: 15139.5;;;;;;;;;;; (why all those commas appeared? ) Thanks!